# PHP Date Between

Tags: php, date

Need to check wether a given date is in between two given dates using PHP, This is the code I've written:

```
$today = date_create('28-Feb-2012');
$fromdate = date_create('20-Feb-2012');
$todate = date_create('22-Feb-2012'); 
if ($today>=$fromdate && $todat<=$todate)
{
    echo 'in range';
}
else
{
    echo 'not in range';
}
```

But this always returns `in range`. Can't figure out where the problem is. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's a bit of a hacky solution, but I tend to use strtotime() for that kind of thing, as it returns an integer:

```
$today = time();
$fromdate = strtotime('20-Feb-2012');
$todate = strtotime('22-Feb-2012'); 
if ($today>=$fromdate && $today<=$todate)
{
    echo 'in range';
}
else
{
    echo 'not in range';
}
```

EDIT: i assume the `$todat` was just a typo into stackoverflow, and that in your code you actually have `$today`, but if not that might be your problem - undefined variables, in some settings, can be considered 0 I believe.

Comment: Actually $todate is a typo in my code :(. Thanks for pointing it out. Your code works fine, I'm using it. Thanks.

Comment: you might consider changing you settings in php.ini to throw up warnings when you use undefined variables. Yes you'll have to pepper your code with variable definitions, but it's so much better than occasionally typoing a variable and having it silently default to 0 or false, and not knowing why your code isn't working

Comment: FYI: changed to `$fromdate = strtotime('20-Feb-2012' . '-1 days');` to make it select the same day

Comment: nice, I didn't know you could subtract days like that. What is that accomplishing? wouldn't the $fromdate as it is start at midnight at the beginning of the 20th of feb?