# If/then statement when dealing with a date

Tags: php, drupal, if-statement

I'm new to PHP and could use a little help figuring this out. I have a drupal website where I have a field that is called **'field_date'**. Inside that field there are two variables (**date1 & date2**) which are the start and end dates. I am trying to create a statement that says:

**If the current date is between date1 and date2 then display 'x'. If it is out of that date range then display 'y'.**

I can also get the current date by using the drupal date variable:

```
format_date(time(), 'custom', 'F d Y');
```

Thanks for anyone able to assist. I really do appreciate it!

UPDATE: For anyone that has this same question I got some help [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53452/reference-start-date-and-end-date-for-date-field/).

Comment: See [PHP Date Between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346174/php-date-between).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your variables into one form and put them into if-statement

```
$now = time();
$date1 = strtotime($date1);
$date2 = strtotime($date2);
if ( $now >= $date1 && $now <= $date2) {
    echo 'x';
} else {
    echo 'y';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vlcekmi3, that looks good. I am just having problems making it work. $now is printing out "13557761811" and $date1 is printing out "1". I have $date1 set to ISO format.

Comment: Also you have a variable '$today'...should that be '$now' also?

Comment: Thanks. This might be more of a drupal question, but would you know how to reference the field that contains the date1 and date2 strings? I am thinking that right now the code above doesn't reference the 'field_date' field.

Answer (score 0):

here we go

```
     $current_day = 'some day here';
    $start_day = strtotime('20-Feb-2012');    // or how u have the date
    $end_day = strtotime('22-Feb-2012');        // or how u have the date
    if ($current_day >=$start_day && $current_day<=$end_day)
   {
        echo 'x';
   }
   else
   {
       echo 'y';
   }
```